# URL Rewrite, handling unwanted url propagation

Tags: html, url-rewriting

My website's navigation bar has the following url links

```
link1="project/one"
link2="project/two"
etc.
```

If I click on **link1** then my RewriteRule will direct the page to show a url at *domain.com/project/one* which is good. Here is the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^project/([A-z0-9]+)$ project.php?p=$1
```

Now I am at *domain.com/project/one*, my navigation links are **still the same** as above, and when I click on **link2** then my RewriteRule fires and logically it takes me to *domain.com/project/project/two*, but that is not what I want.  What I want is domain.com/project/two.

I'm new to URL rewrites, can someone point me in the right direction about how to handle this? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get relative links to work with my .htaccess rules by adding the base html tag with my siteroot set as the href in my page header.  I have never heard of this tag before I ran into it searching for answers so I'm not sure how legit this is, but it does do what I want it to.

```
<base href="domain.com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This not because of rewrite.

Your link is relative to the current url. To get what you need 
Make those links like

```
link1="/project/one"
link2="/project/two"
```

Your url rewrite internally shows the content from

`project.php?p=one` and `project.php?p=two`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand the problem of the link being relative to the current url. If I make my links "/project/one" like you suggest then when I click on the link it treats "/project" as the root which results in the page Not Found. I want it to direct to domain/project/one. Do I have to put the absolute path in my links or something? I just thought there would be another way other then using abs path.

Comment: What is not working /project/ or /project/one ?. Where have you put the rewrite?. .htaccess ?. Where is this .htaccess is located ?